# Putting 2 queries together

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I put these two queries together?  I know the magic is in the joins.

```
SELECT tblCanisterNew.CountyOperatorID
    ,tblCanisterNew.Year
    ,Sum(Nz([value])) AS RevenueMiles
    ,0 AS TotalExpenses
FROM tblCanisterNew
WHERE (
        ((tblCanisterNew.typeID) = 4)
        AND (
            (CLng([elementkey])) IN (6021, 6022, 60, 23, 6024, 6025))
        )
GROUP BY tblCanisterNew.CountyOperatorID
    ,tblCanisterNew.Year

UNION

SELECT tblCanisterNew.CountyOperatorID
    ,tblCanisterNew.Year
    ,0 AS RevenueMiles
    ,Sum(Nz([value])) AS TotalExpenses
FROM tblCanisterNew
WHERE (
        ((tblCanisterNew.typeID) = 4)
        AND (
            (CLng([elementkey])) IN (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014))
        )
GROUP BY tblCanisterNew.CountyOperatorID
    ,tblCanisterNew.Year;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "together"? They're already being Unioned. What are you *actually* after here? Sample data and expected results might give us a little more insight.

Comment: Show us some sample result for each SELECT, and also the combined result.

Comment: The two queries are very similar, so I assume you can "merge" them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
SELECT tc.CountyOperatorID, tc.Year, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN CLng([elementkey]) IN (6021,6022,60,23,6024,6025) THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS RevenueMiles,
       Sum(CASE WHEN CLng([elementkey]) IN (1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014) THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS TotalExpenses
FROM tblCanisterNew tc
WHERE tc.typeID = 4 
GROUP BY tc.CountyOperatorID, tc.Year;
```

Note : SQL Server doesn't' have `CLng()`, equivalent function would be `convert(bigint, elementkey)`. But, as per data you don't need to do conversation.